# Is there any way to not track a object after it has been recognized once in YOLOv8?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

**Is there any way to not detect a object in a video after it has been detected once in a video?** I am using **Yolov8 with cv2** and wanted to know if there any possible way to track a id of an object that has been **detected in a frame and print its id and class** and then **not print that specific id and its class in the next frames for 5s.**

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import cvzone
import math
import numpy as np
from sort import *
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("resources/video.mp4")
#cap.set(3, 1280)
#cap.set(4, 720)


model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

classNames = ["person", "bicycle", "car", "motorbike", "aeroplane", "bus", "train", "truck", "boat",
              "traffic light", "fire hydrant", "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench", "bird", "cat",
              "dog", "horse", "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", "backpack", "umbrella",
              "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", "skis", "snowboard", "sports ball", "kite", "baseball bat",
              "baseball glove", "skateboard", "surfboard", "tennis racket", "bottle", "wine glass", "cup",
              "fork", "knife", "spoon", "bowl", "banana", "apple", "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli",
              "carrot", "hot dog", "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair", "sofa", "pottedplant", "bed",
              "diningtable", "toilet", "tvmonitor", "laptop", "mouse", "remote", "keyboard", "cell phone",
              "microwave", "oven", "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator", "book", "clock", "vase", "scissors",
              "teddy bear", "hair drier", "toothbrush"
              ]

tracker = Sort(max_age=20, min_hits=3, iou_threshold=0.3)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    results = model(img, stream=True)

    detections = np.empty((0, 5))

    for r in results:
        boxes = r.boxes
        for box in boxes:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
            w, h = x2-x1, y2-y1
            bbox = int(x1), int(y1), int(w), int(h)
            cvzone.cornerRect(img, bbox)
            conf = math.ceil((box.conf[0]*100))/100
            cls = int(box.cls[0])
            cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'{classNames[cls]},{conf}', (max(0,x1),max(35,y1)))
            currentArray = np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2, conf])
            detections = np.vstack((detections, currentArray))

    resultsTracker = tracker.update(detections)

    for result in resultsTracker:
            x1, y1, x2, y2, id = result
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
            print(result)
            w, h = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
            cvzone.cornerRect(img, (x1, y1, w, h), l=9, rt=2, colorR=(255, 0, 255))
            cvzone.putTextRect(img, f' {int(id)},{conf}', (max(0, x1), max(35, y1)),
                            scale=2, thickness=3, offset=10)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have tried a different approach as well by simply **destroying the window for the next 5s** but that isn't working for my use case

```
import time

from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import cvzone
import math

def capture_ai(value):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(value)
    cap.set(3, 1280)
    cap.set(4, 720)

    model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

    classNames = ["person", "bicycle", "car", "motorbike", "aeroplane", "bus", "train", "truck", "boat",
                  "traffic light", "fire hydrant", "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench", "bird", "cat",
                  "dog", "horse", "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", "backpack", "umbrella",
                  "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", "skis", "snowboard", "sports ball", "kite", "baseball bat",
                  "baseball glove", "skateboard", "surfboard", "tennis racket", "bottle", "wine glass", "cup",
                  "fork", "knife", "spoon", "bowl", "banana", "apple", "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli",
                  "carrot", "hot dog", "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair", "sofa", "pottedplant", "bed",
                  "diningtable", "toilet", "tvmonitor", "laptop", "mouse", "remote", "keyboard", "cell phone",
                  "microwave", "oven", "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator", "book", "clock", "vase", "scissors",
                  "teddy bear", "hair drier", "toothbrush"
                  ]
    IdentifiedClassNames = {"person":0, "bicycle":0, "car":0, "motorbike":0, "aeroplane":0, "bus":0, "train":0, "truck":0, "boat":0,
                  "traffic light":0, "fire hydrant":0, "stop sign":0, "parking meter":0, "bench":0, "bird":0, "cat":0,
                  "dog":0, "horse":0, "sheep":0, "cow":0, "elephant":0, "bear":0, "zebra":0, "giraffe":0, "backpack":0, "umbrella":0,
                  "handbag":0, "tie":0, "suitcase":0, "frisbee":0, "skis":0, "snowboard":0, "sports ball":0, "kite":0, "baseball bat":0,
                  "baseball glove":0, "skateboard":0, "surfboard":0, "tennis racket":0, "bottle":0, "wine glass":0, "cup":0,
                  "fork":0, "knife":0, "spoon":0, "bowl":0, "banana":0, "apple":0, "sandwich":0, "orange":0, "broccoli":0,
                  "carrot":0, "hot dog":0, "pizza":0, "donut":0, "cake":0, "chair":0, "sofa":0, "pottedplant":0, "bed":0,
                  "diningtable":0, "toilet":0, "tvmonitor":0, "laptop":0, "mouse":0, "remote":0, "keyboard":0, "cell phone":0,
                  "microwave":0, "oven":0, "toaster":0, "sink":0, "refrigerator":0, "book":0, "clock":0, "vase":0, "scissors":0,
                  "teddy bear":0, "hair drier":0, "toothbrush":0}

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        results = model(img, stream=True)
        for r in results:
            boxes = r.boxes
            for box in boxes:
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
                w, h = x2-x1, y2-y1
                bbox = int(x1), int(y1), int(w), int(h)
                cvzone.cornerRect(img, bbox)
                conf = math.ceil((box.conf[0]*100))/100
                cls = int(box.cls[0])
                cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'{classNames[cls]},{conf}', (max(0,x1),max(35,y1)))
                cls = int(box.cls[0])
                identify = classNames[cls]
                IdentifiedClassNames[identify] += 1
                for key, value in IdentifiedClassNames.items():
                    if IdentifiedClassNames[key] == 0:
                        continue
                    elif IdentifiedClassNames[key] == 1:
                        print(value, ":", key)
                        IdentifiedClassNames[key] = 0
                    else:
                        print(value, ":", key+"s")
                        IdentifiedClassNames[key] = 0

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        time.sleep(5)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cv2.imshow("Image", img)



capture_ai(0)
```

I had another approach where I add the certain ids of objects detected in a frame into array and then not detect the id's that were not in that array, and then clear that array after 5s. However I wasn't able to implement it.